# How best to optimize nginx rules and handle dynamic IPs?

Tags: optimization, dynamic, nginx, ip, config

I have just made the switch from running my site on apache over to nginx, but I have a few questions:

1. I have converted my htaccess rules into a config for the vhost, however there seems to be a lot of repeating, so I'm looking to see if its possible to condense it down. For example, I have multiple directories I want to block a list of extensions for, at the moment I have a location for every directory and then the same list of denied extensions for them. I have then had to repeat all of these again in the SSL "version" of the server.
2. With Apache, I used to specify htaccess rules which only permitted certain IPs to an admin directory. Although I have this working on nginx, the IPs are dynamic IPs, and I used to run a script via cron which would update the htaccess files with the current dynamic ip after performing a lookup on a dyndns hostname. Is there anyway to permit dynamic IPs on nginx, or is the only way to have the script restart nginx every time it updates the config file?

Thanks.